# Invalid instantiation exception when pass dynamic object to custom interpolated string handler in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, string-interpolation, c#-10.0

I found an issue upgrading to the .NET 6 `LogErrorInterpolatedStringHandler` in my logger method.

Here is the classic method:

```
public static void Log(string message, params object[] pars)
{
    // Log message
}
```

and here is the upgraded one:

```
public static void Log(ref LogErrorInterpolatedStringHandler message, params object[] pars)
{
    // Log message
}
```

I upgraded the method in order to get the performance improvements of C# 10 and .NET 6 described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/string-interpolation-in-c-10-and-net-6/).

The new version of the method works well except when passing `dynamic` object in the interpolated string.

Here is an example:

```
// Works well   
Logger.Log($"Log: {stringOrEverythingElseObject}");

// Exception
Logger.Log($"Log: {dynamicObject}");
```

The exception thrown is

> The generic type '<>A{00000004}`3' was used with an invalid instantiation in assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I found [a pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/55642) similar to my problem but could not understand how to fix in my code.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There is not much you can do except casting `dynamicObject` to `object` at the call site:

```
Logger.Log($"Log: {(object)dynamicObject}");
```

or removing `ref` from the handler:

```
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public struct LogErrorInterpolatedStringHandler
```

But not sure how it will affect performance (though using `dynamic` should have much more effect on performance than this, in general you should avoid `dynamic` in performance sensitive code)

**Attempt to explain**

`ref struct`s do not work with `dynamic` very well due to the [following limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#ref-struct):

> - A `ref` struct can't be a type argument.

While code handling the `dynamic` uses the related types as type parameters. I.e. the following code:

```cs
var handler = new Handler();
handler.AppendFormatted((dynamic)5);

ref struct Handler
{
    // or public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value) { }
    public void AppendFormatted(object value) { }
}
```

Will result in something like this [generated by compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATABgLABQ2AjIQG4CGUABABYUB2AJgDYw0C81DMA7tQAlGrdgAoAlAG5C9ZmygA6AIIAHFTGYAxaAFsKAF30wmo0UwCeDCjoCWYcQFYphQrABm1AM76oAVzD6gsLyhADehNSR1AD00dTQ1BgAzIko1KrqWroGRkwAPAAqAHyiBdSULL4w4tSh1AC+EVHJqelqGkzaUHqGxqIQwABWMAHlFJXVtQ2E9UA):

```
private static class <>o__0
{
    public static CallSite<<>A{00000002}<CallSite, Handler, object>> <>p__0;
}
```

Note the `Handler` in the list of type parameters which will lead to the exactly the same runtime error. Removing `ref` from the handler fixes the issue.

As noted in comments in this [test](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e37f01d872be3e2809e39e87fe14c24e61a952e7/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Semantic/Semantics/InterpolationTests.cs#L14712) and [this comment by Stephen Toub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55609#issuecomment-898636629) currently Roslyn does not emit any build time errors for this code while it fails in runtime.